# Python Count Leading and Trailing Whitespace

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe *note the leading and trailing whitespace in the stings*:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['foo ', ' bar', ' baz ', 'beetle juice']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to count all strings that have leading and\or trailing whitespace but ignore whitespace in the middle of the sting.

So, in the example above, the whitespace count should equal 3.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does what you want.

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['foo ', ' bar', ' baz ', 'beetle juice']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
count = 0

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0][0] == " " or row[0][-1] == " ":
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

With [.str accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) you can achieve it in one line:

```
(df[0].str.startswith(" ") | df[0].str.endswith(" ")).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `defaultdict` from `collection` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict as df

data = ['foo ', ' bar', ' baz ', 'beetle juice']
result = df(int)

for elm in data:
    if elm.startswith(' '):
        result['leading'] += 1
    elif elm.endswith(' '):
        result['trailing'] += 1

print(result)
print(dict(result))
count = sum(k for k in result.values())
print(count)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'trailing': 1, 'leading': 2})
{'trailing': 1, 'leading': 2}
3
```